# Binding an array in knex - Expected 4 bindings, saw 1

Tags: sql, knex.js

I am trying to write this query in knex

```
select conversation
from participants
group by conversation
having array_agg(participants.user order by participants.user) = array[3,16,17,18]
```

I have done this in knex

```
await knex( 'participants' )
  .select( 'conversation' )
  .groupBy( 'conversation' )
  .havingRaw( 'array_agg(participants.user order by participants.user) = ?', [3,16,17,18] )
```

I am getting the error

```
Expected 4 bindings, saw 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
await knex( 'participants' )
  .select( 'conversation' )
  .groupBy( 'conversation' )
  .havingRaw( 'array_agg(participants.user order by participants.user) = array[?,?,?,?]', [3,16,17,18])
```

Knex really doesn't support automatic conversion of array bindings well, since in SQL syntax there are many different syntaxes (at least `(1,2,3)`, `{1,2,3}`, and `[1,2,3]`... probably event more) and one would have to be able to tell it which one to use.